# Excel - display amount in a different currency on mouse over / cell selection?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on an Excel spreadsheet that uses a currency other than my native and I'd like to see quick and convenient currency conversions, possibly in the status bar (like when you select multiple cells and you see AVG and SUM there) or in a tooltip, kind of like with comments. All methods I've seen so far use additional cells and add-ins such as [this one](http://www.office-plugins.net/free-excel-currency-converter/).

Two questions:

1. Is this possible in the first place? Does Excel have extensibility model that would allow this?
2. Does such tool exist?

Thanks.

Comment: No, this does not occur natively. I mean you could make an on selection macro to do it, but that would be pretty clunky.

Comment: I know this is not built in. But does such macro / add-in exist? Can it be done? I.e., does Excel provide extensibility points to hook into the status bar and/or tooltips?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: There has been an excellent answer already, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any text or number on the **status bar** with VBA.

Copy this on VBA to the sheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    q = Target.Value
    qRow = Target.Row
    qColumn = Target.Column
    If IsNumeric(q) Then
        m = moneyconverter(q)
        Application.StatusBar = m & " €"
    Else
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End If
End Sub

Public Function moneyconverter(originalmoney As Variant)
    moneyconverter = (originalmoney / 3)
End Function
```

There are two parts:

- *Worksheet_SelectionChange*: Here is the detection of the selected cell.
- *moneyconverter function*: here you have to put the currency conversion. For demonstrations purposes I assumed it was the original currency divided by 3 and the currency units were Euros (€).

The values will appear on the left side of the status bar and will be there even if you change to another opened workbook. To clear the value, in the original sheet select a text cell.

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way to have this behavior on all sheets without the need to copy/paste to every sheet? (Sorry I never really worked with VBA.)

Comment: @Borek I've modified the code to make it work for every sheet. You have to delete the old one and copy the new one to **ThisWorkbook** on VBA.

Comment: @Borek On the line `Application.StatusBar = m & " €"` change the `€`symbol to anything you want / need.

Comment: It works for me only if I go to Sheet1 -> View code and paste it, not when I paste it to ThisWorkbook -> View code.

Comment: @Borek. I modfied the code on the answer to make it work on the full workbook instead of a single sheet. Don't cut and paste the **old code** because it won't work. Copy **the code on the answer** and *paste* it on *ThisWorkbook*

Comment: Updated it a little bit to keep the standard status bar for zero values and to respond to worksheet switching. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/borekb/4da4504081393ec536a0).

Comment: @Borek Great!!!